# Confusion in deduction of Hermite's Identity.

Tags: functions

I was following the proof of identity [here](https://brilliant.org/wiki/hermites-identity/).

Before the proof, it wrote a relation $$\lfloor x\rfloor\le \left\lfloor x + \frac{1}{n}\right\rfloor \le \cdots \le \left\lfloor x + \frac{n-1}{n} \right\rfloor  
$$ & showed that each term can take two values $\lfloor x\rfloor$ & $\lfloor x\rfloor + 1$.

Now, can anyone explain me how the page wrote the above relation? And what does it mean that they can take only two values??

Comment: You should ensure your question is actually reflective of what is presented in the proof. Namely, use floor function brackets $\lfloor \rfloor$

Comment: @DonkeyKong: Mine is also right, sir, isn't it? BTW, how to type that??

Comment: In the past people often wrote $[x]$ for the floor function evaluated at $x$.  I think software, probably Knuth's $\TeX$, is what made the "floor function brackets" possible. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: @Michael Hardy; Thanks, sir, for editing:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number $\left\lfloor x + \frac 1 n \right\rfloor$ is necessarily at least as big as $\lfloor x\rfloor$ but may or may not be at least as big as $\lfloor x\rfloor + 1$, depending on what numbers $x$ and $n$ are.  Suppose, for example that $x=5.8$ and $n=12$.  Then
$$
\left\lfloor x + \frac 1 n \right\rfloor = \lfloor 5.88333\ldots\rfloor = 5 = \lfloor x\rfloor.
$$
However, suppose $x=5.8$ and $n=4$.  Then
$$
\left\lfloor x + \frac 1 n \right\rfloor = \lfloor 6.05\rfloor = 6 = \lfloor x \rfloor + 1.
$$

Comment: +1; Sir, can you tell me how the site wrote $$\lfloor x\rfloor\le \left\lfloor x + \frac{1}{n}\right\rfloor \le \cdots \le \left\lfloor x + \frac{n-1}{n} \right\rfloor $$? I'm not getting the sense how it is true. Can you please explain analytically?? I'll be grateful:)

Comment: Have you drawn the graph of $x\mapsto\lfloor x\rfloor$?  First try a table like this: $$\begin{array}{|c|c|} x & \lfloor x\rfloor \vphantom{\frac 1 1} \\  \hline  4 & 4 \\ 4.2 & 4 \\ 4.4 & 4 \\ 4.6 & 4 \\ 4.8 & 4 \\ 5 & 5 \\ 5.2 & 5 \\ 5.4 & 5 \\ 5.6 & 5 \\ 5.8 & 5 \\ 6 & 6 \\ 6.2 & 6 \\ 6.4 & 6 \\ \vdots & \vdots  \end{array}$$ Plot some points and see if you get a sense of how this function behaves. Note in particular that as $x$ gets bigger then $\lfloor x\rfloor$ never gets smaller. That last fact is why the sequence of inequalities must be true. ${}\qquad{}$